# Save JavaPairRDD to Cassandra

Tags: java, apache-spark, cassandra, rdd, spark-cassandra-connector

I am attempting to put a Spark created JavaPairRDD into Cassandra. There are a lot of examples for JavaRDDs but not so much for PairRDDs.

My JavaPairRDD looks like this:

```
JavaPairRDD<String, List<Tuple<String, Long>>> pairs
```

And I am trying to save to a Cassandra Table with the columns defined as follows:

```
name TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
list LIST<TUPLE<STRING, LONG>>
```

I know I will probably have to use javaFunctions from the cassandra utils, however I am not sure about the syntax nor do I understand what RowWriterFactory is supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

JavaPairRDD contains Tuple2. You can try below code but I don't think generic collection type is supported as class type in `CassandraJavaUtil.mapTupleToRow` function which returns `RowWriterFactory`. You can find details of `mapTupleToRow` at https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/7_java_api.md

```
javaFunctions(javaPairRDD).writerBuilder("cassandrakeyspace", "cassandratable", CassandraJavaUtil.mapTupleToRow(A.class, B.class)).saveToCassandra();
```